# InstallShield - Update components destination which include product version

Tags: installshield

I have Basic MSI setup and several component are being installed under [CommonAppDataFolder]AAA\BBB\2210,
2210 is the product version so every time we have a new version I need to update the path which is very bad.
I don't know how to solve that as if I replace 2210 with ProductVersion or other property it doesn't work.
Please advise.
(My goal is when moving to a new version I will just update a property or use Automation Interface with .vbs script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done using custom action which must be scheduled after CostFinalize  action. In Vb script, session.TargetPath could be used to set directory.

Once [productVersion] property is used, you don't need to change anything with future release.